# Window store doesn't open

Tags: windows-10, windows-store

Whenever I open Windows Store this screen appear and won't me browse the store (see below). how do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try resetting windows store cache.
If you are using Windows 10 v1607 and later you can goto settings apps and features and select windows store then advanced options and reset.
If you are using older windows search wsreset in start and run it as administrator.
Still not working use windows apps trouble shooter http://aka.ms/diag_apps10

If nothing works reinstall windows store
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-store-app-missing-windows-10

Comment: If Windows Store doesn't open it's unlikely the Settings application will open.